# Leaflet issue: Marker and polygon not agreeing on locations?

Tags: leaflet

I've got a leaflet map, to which I added a GeoJSON object (a polygon, specifically) and a number of Markers. The markers should all be inside the polygon, but they're not being displayed that way:

[image: Marker and Polygon strangeness]

In the example below, the GeoJSON is:

`{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[29.53125,49.921875],[29.53125,50.625],[30.9375,50.625],[30.9375,49.921875],[29.53125,49.921875]]]}`

And the green-highlighted marker's coordinates are:
`[30.9332103729, 50.3615112305]`

As you can see that marker is showing up well outside the outline of the polygon. The problem is considerably worse at wider zoom levels -- zoomed all the way in, the green marker makes its way just *barely* inside the polygon outline.

Any idea what could be causing this?

**UPDATE:**
Turns out the issue appears to be the Markers, not the GeoJSON... when I zoom in on the map, the markers move. In this example, they all move to the northwest as I zoom in.

Comment: I can not reproduce - see http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/lej/edit?html,output

Comment: Maybe it's specific to L.geoJson(...)?

Comment: Can you show us the exact GeoJSON that you're using?

Comment: @IvanSanchez see edit for GeoJSON.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Well, that's odd. I just dropped that GeoJSON into your playground, and it seems completely fine. Must be something else wrong.... will hopefully return here with an edit if I either figure it out or find other potential issues.

Comment: (another update)...

Comment: Dan, by any chance are you using the `iconAnchor` option in your custom icons?

Comment: @IvanSanchez *AHA!!!!* That's it! I was not. Just tried turning off the custom icons, and voila, everything worked fine. Please turn that comment into an answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the data, the comments, and some tests, it seems that the problem was in the misuse of the [`iconAnchor` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#icon) for the marker's icons.

Even though the "tip" of the marker icon image is out of the rectangle, the top-left corner of the markers is always within the rectangle, which indicates that the `iconAnchor` option has a value of `[0, 0]`. Adjusting this value to fit the "tip" should fix the visual issue.